# Does an app exists that tells me if I am in the correct train in Belgium?

Tags: public-transport, online-resources

I am sitting in a Belgian train. The announcement on the electronic information panel in train is indicating contradictory information to what staff told me when I started my trip. There is no authority in sight.

I do have connection to the internet. Does a website or app exist that can tell me where I am and what the next stops are going to be?

I know that the Thalys offers this on their on-board intranet. There you simply connect to their wifi and you'll see where you are. I am wondering if a similar service exist for normal trains and buses.

Comment: Why don't you simply ask someone sitting next to you? Have people forgotten how to communicate with other humans just because something *could* be found on the internet?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo why do you assume I didn't? I find you comment quite offensive. Please don't draw conclusions on incorrect assumptions.

Comment: Because if you did, it would have solved your problem and you would not have had to ask here.

Comment: @andra: If you find that question "quite offensive" I think it suggests you're taking things a little too personally.

Comment: It's not the first question *per se*, it's the comment, its tone and context…

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. For you it could be easier to ask someone, but some people preffer or even have to use an app for some reasons.

Comment: @Dirty-flow: It may of course be a problem that it for some reason is not possible to communicate with other passengers on the train, but then the question lacks an explanation why this utterly obvious solution cannot be used. If there is e.g. a language barrier, it won't help to suggest using an app, which is only available in Dutch or French.

Comment: Andra might be the only person in the carriage. This has happened to me before.

Comment: @JoshB: That's likely one of the least probable explanations. "I am sitting in a Belgian train ..." around 10AM on a weekday. I doubt that you'll find such a train in Belgium without other passengers.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Asking someone else is an option sure. Maybe andra speaks the language. What about me eh? Should I not travel in trains in Belgium if I cannot *ask* someone about the information. I agree with the others. The tone in your comment was rude and offensive. And as JoshB mentioned, Andra could be the only person in the carriage (is it necessary to take the train at 10am in the morning).

Comment: @Aditya: As I wrote in my comment to Dirty-Flow: Unless andra (or you) explain *why* you can't ask someone else, it is impossible to suggest an alternative solution, since it is not unlikely that the reason not being able to use the obvious solution also will hinder you from using any alternative solution being suggested. The language barrer was only *one* possibility.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Language barrier is one possibility. Lack of social skills is another. Empty train is a third possibility. Being unsure of their answer is another. I think these are a good amount of reasons as to why this is important. For me very specifically, I'd prefer to avoid asking someone else. Just ask someone who knows will be a valid reason for half of the things on this website. **A source or a proof or a system which does not depend on memory is appreciated.**

Comment: @Tor-EinarJambjo I don't think that adding those details would improve the question perse. These comments however are contra productive. I add a specific meta post to discuss the matter: http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1818/rule-2-dont-judge-peoples-motivations-for-traveling

Comment: @Aditya: "Just ask someone who knows" is very unlikely a good answer to many of the questions here, since it simply raises a new question: "Where can I find someone who knows?", to which the answer may very well be "On travel.stackexchange.com". In this case, according to the question, the questioner is very likely within close vicinity of several other people able to help. But I've written a longer explanation in the meta post, hopefully that will contribute to something.

Comment: If staff and electronic screen provide contradictory information, are you going to trust a third source better? And why?

Answer (score 2):

I use Google Maps or Apple Maps, but you could use any mapping software that shows your position via GPS. Find your target city and compare your current position with the destination. You should be able to trace back your position on marked railway lines on the map back too where you are.

Comment: That wouldn't tell you what stations the train will call at.

Comment: @Gilles Actually it sometimes does. I don't know if it works everywhere where Google Maps transport does, but the past 3 weeks I've been in Japan. If it shows say, the Hikari Shinkansen between Tokyo and Osaka, and I click it, it then shows me all the stops inbetween as well that *this* particular train will stop at. Same with Tokyo metro, so both intra and inter-city transport.